# Debugging errors in c++

Tags: c++, debugging, unix

I was working on a program that printed out the word count, character count and line count depending on the user's input. But I keep getting these error that are completely unknown to me. I was wondering if anyone could help.
** I've changed it from previous mistakes and am still receiving errors. Sorry I'm new to C++.

The errors I got were

```
 filestat.cpp:47: error: ‘line’ was not declared in this scope
 filestat.cpp: In function ‘int wc(std::string)’:
 filestat.cpp:55: error: ‘line’ was not declared in this scope
 filestat.cpp: In function ‘int cc(std::string)’:
 filestat.cpp:67: error: ‘line’ was not declared in this scope


#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int lc(string fname);
int wc(string fname);
int cc(string fname);

int main(){
string fname,line,command;
ifstream ifs;
int i;
while(true){
    cout<<"---- Enter a file name : ";

    if(getline(cin,line)){
        if(line.length()== 4 && line.compare("exit")== 0){
            cout<<"Exiting";
            exit(0);
        }else{
            string command = line.substr(0,2);
            fname= line.substr(4, line.length() -5);
                if( ifs.fail()){
                    ifs.open(fname.c_str());
                    cerr<< "File not found" <<fname <<endl;
                    ifs.clear();
                }else{
                    if(command.compare("lc")){
                        lc(fname);
                    }else if (command.compare("wc")){
                        wc(fname);
                    }else  if(command.compare("cc")){           
                                      cc(fname);                    
                    }else
                        cout<<"Command unknown. ";


                }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}

 int lc(string fname){
 int count;
 while(getline(fname, line)){
    count++;
 }
  cout<<"Number of lines: "<<count ; 
   }

  int wc(string fname){
int count;
while(getline(fname, line)){
    int pos=line.find_first_of("\n\t ",0);
    while(pos =! string::npos){
        int length=line.length();
        line = line.substr(pos+1, length - pos);
        count++;
    }
  }
cout<< "Number of words: " <<count; 
  }
 int cc(string fname){
int count;
while(getline(fname, line)){
    count = count + line.length();
}

cout<< "Number of words: " <<count;

    }
```

When I set line as a global variable I get the error:

> filestat.cpp:48: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’

Comment: You could make this code a lot more readable by using indentation properly. (Perhaps you were mixing space characters with tab characters. Never a good idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have other errors.  Firstly, you need to have a local variable `line` in each of your `wc`, `lc`, and `cc` functions.

Secondly, you cannot call `getline` using `fname`.  It expects an `istream`.  So why don't you pass `ifs` into your functions?

```
int wc( ifstream &ifs )
{
    string line;
    int count = 0;
    while(getline(fname, line)){
        int pos=line.find_first_of("\n\t ",0);
        while(pos =! string::npos){
            int length=line.length();
            line = line.substr(pos+1, length - pos);
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout<< "Number of words: " <<count;
    return count;
}
```

In the above, I also initialised `count` and returned it (since you have an int return type and were not returning anything).

Similar changes for your other functions.

By the way, you might want to lookup the `string::find_first_of` function and decide whether you really need to replace `line` with a substring every time.  Look at the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have declared `line`, it is a local variable of the `main` function. You can't use it in the other functions (`cc`, `wc` etc.).

Either declare it as a global variable, or pass it as an argument to `cc`, `wc` and the other functions.

Comment: When I declare it as a global variable I then get the error

Comment: [filestat.cpp:48: error: cannot convert ‘std::string’ to ‘char**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘__ssize_t getline(char**, size_t*, FILE*)’]

Comment: to convert from string to char* you do line.c_str() and for the extra * in char** you do &line.c_str()

Comment: It changes the error now to  error: invalid lvalue in unary ‘&’ . After converting the string to char**

Answer (score 0):

As your errors state, `line` was not declared in the "scope" (i.e. functions) listed. You need to make `line` a global variable (meaning declared outside of `main`) if you want them accessible to those functions.

Answer (score 0):

ok so besides declaring line in global scope. you need to create a ifstream object from filename  in the problematic functions. for e.g.

```
int cc(string fname){
ifstream f(fname);
int count;
while(getline(f, line)){
    count = count + line.length();
}
f.close();
}
```

this should do, but I would recommend to change function definitions to

```
 int cc(ifstream& f);
```